# how to access stdclass object inside stdclass object in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

In the Cron controller I have written the following function:-

```
public function football() {
        $jsonData = file_get_contents('http://localhost/football/football/api/football_api.php');        

    }

$jsonData is returning the following object:-



    stdClass Object
(
    [callum-paterson] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [unique_id] => callum-paterson
            [name] => Callum Paterson
            [club] => Cardiff City
            [position] => Defender
            [national_team_name] => Unknown
            [birthdate] => 1994-10-13
            [birthplace] => Unknown
            [nationality] => Unknown
            [preferred_foot] => Unknown
            [weight] => 76
            [height] => 183
            [shirt_number] => 13
            [real_position] => Full Back
            [real_position_side] => Right
            [country] => Scotland
            [photo_url] => https://img.footballindex.co.uk/callum-paterson-g-t1.jpg
        )

    [chicharito] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [unique_id] => chicharito
            [name] => Chicharito
            [club] => West Ham United
            [position] => Forward
            [national_team_name] => Unknown
            [birthdate] => 1988-06-01
            [birthplace] => Guadalajara
            [nationality] => Mexico
            [preferred_foot] => Right
            [weight] => 73
            [height] => 175
            [shirt_number] => 17
            [real_position] => Striker
            [real_position_side] => Centre
            [country] => Mexico
            [photo_url] => https://img.footballindex.co.uk/javier-hernandez-g-t6.jpg
        )
```

$jsonData is returning 1064 records. Here I'm showing a few. so I want to print all the records(like id,unique_id,name etc.) inside the stdclass-object_index(like [callum-paterson] ).

I'm new to JSON. So I cannot do it. Any help will be appreciated. I tried foreach but it's not working.

Comment: use `json_decode` in your `foreach` loop - take a look @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: +sintakonte can u give me an example??

Comment: On the line under `file_get_contents`, can you `echo gettype($jsonData)`? I don’t think that’s an array.

Comment: Hey it was n't coming in proper JSON format so I updated the api. You can check the updated code now.

Comment: You need to show us what the `gettype()` is of `$jsonData`.

Comment: +Thomas Edwards `gettype()` is of `$jsonData` is returning **object**

Comment: `file_get_contents()` returns a string, so it’s confusing that you’re getting an object. Are you doing something else you’re not showing us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem here is my solution:-

```
public function football() {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $tmp = array();
        $footballers = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost/football/football/api/football_api.php'));

        foreach ($footballers as $footballer => $data) {
            $tmp[] = $data->unique_id;
        }
        print_r($tmp);

    }
```

$tmp holds all the unique_ids. Like that You can print all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using variable names that are the type of data. What they contain is more useful. `$data` is acceptable when the variable is not yet useful.

```
public function football() {
    $footballers = file_get_contents('http://localhost/football/football/api/football_api.php');

    foreach ($footballers as $footballer => $data) {
        $footballers[$footballer] = json_decode($data);
    }

    return $footballers;
}
```

Comment: `$footballers` returns `Array ( [callum-paterson] => { "id": "1", "unique_id": "callum-paterson", "name": "Callum Paterson", "club": "Cardiff City", "position": "Defender", "national_team_name": "Unknown", "birthdate": "1994-10-13", "birthplace": "Unknown", "nationality": "Unknown", "preferred_foot": "Unknown", "weight": "76", "height": "183", "shirt_number": "13", "real_position": "Full Back", "real_position_side": "Right", "country": "Scotland", "photo_url": "https:\/\/img.footballindex.co.uk\/callum-paterson-g-t1.jpg" }` which is not expected.  I want the value of **id** which is 1.

Comment: Using this, you would then use `foreach ($footballers as $footballer) { echo $footballer->id; } to return the ID, but there are other issues, I’ve asked a question on your post.